# How to scale a part of a curve horizontally and vertically?

Tags: plotting

I have some data for curves, say $y(x,t)$, in which $x$ and $y$ cover different ranges. I need to compare them by shifting and stretching the curve horizontally and vertically.

This is the [data](https://www.transferbigfiles.com/c674d062-ce7b-4a39-8c17-3775291d7362/Jm4iddqJrxLqKdZ6xrnR7g2) for an example function.

The data can be imported by

```
Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/hrk0uMHb", "Table"]
```

I want to scale just the right part of the curve from the $y_{min}$ by the following functions:

$$Y(X)=\frac{y(x,t_0)}{0.01},\quad X=\frac{x-x_{min}}{0.001}$$

I use `NMinimize` to find the $y_{min}=0.440154692$ at $x_{min}=2.06704446$ on the curve $y(x,t_0)$. And the horizontal coordinate range $[x_{min},6.4]$ then need to be adjusted to cover a new range of $[0,6]$. After scaling, I want a curve like this. [This](https://www.transferbigfiles.com/26abe7de-c677-46f2-b8ea-7466a08eb75c/wZvU3lKroRT-bWNoHzSqPQ2) is the data for the target curve. I want to show a best overlap between my rescaled curve and the target curve.

[image]

Thanks!

Thanks for @Jack LaVigne's `scaledData`, from its topological structure, I believe it is the first-scaled curve. Is there any method to rescale the `scaledData` to obtain a curve, which can show a good superposition on the target curve in a range of roughly `{{0,4},{0.2,1.5}}`?

Comment: Solve for $Y(y)=100 y$ and $x(X)=0.001 X+x_{min}$ (yes, capitalization is correct) then plot $Y(y(x(X)),t_r)$ as a function of $X$. `Interpolation` is your friend here.

Comment: @ LLlAMnYP, Thanks,  let me have a try. BTW, can you download the .dat file. It appears to be blocked on some browser... Just check with you.

Comment: It downloaded fine, though dropbox is an unpleasant medium for this. With, say, pastebin I could simply run `Import["http://pastebin.url.for.the.data", "Table"]` and have it in MMA directly, here I needed to copy-paste. After your transformations the `y` range of your plot would be not .5 to 2, as you've shown, but rather 44.0156 to 44.0166.

Comment: There, I've stuck it into a pastebin for you (see edit).

Comment: @ LLlAMnYP, many thanks for your advice!

Comment: `data = Import["c:\\downloads\\tr.dat"];
With[{f = Interpolation[data]}, 
 Plot[ 100 f[( .001 x + Quiet@ArgMin[f@t, t])], {x, 0, 
   Max@data[[All, 1]]}, Evaluated -> True]]`

Comment: Random thought: if you just need the stretched functions to look at, consider PlotRange?

Comment: Hi @ Dr. belisarius, sorry for the late reply. 1. What is your mean by `[f@t, t]` as the argument of `ArgMin`. Just now, I learnt from help and know that it gives a position $x_{min}$ at which f is minimized. But I still don't understand its application here. Because here the instant for my curve is constant $t_r$ 2. I still need to adjust the horizontal coordinate range $[x_{min}, 6.4]$ to cover a new range of [0,6]. Kindly check the last sentence. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I won't repeat getting the `data`.

### Scale the data

First locate the position of the minimum

```
Position[data, Min[data[[All, 2]]]]
(* {{210, 2}} *)

xmin = data[[210, 1]]
(* 2.06705 *)

ymin = data[[210, 2]]
(* 0.440155 *)
```

`Table` is one way to scale the `x` and `y` data

```
scaledData = Table[{(point[[1]] - xmin)/0.001, point[[2]]/0.01}, 
                 {point, data[[210 ;; -1]]}]
```

It looks like this for everything to the right of `xmin`

```
ListLinePlot[scaledData]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In your example scaled plot the x-axis range is 0 to 6. Plotting the scaled data with this range produces a plot that doesn't match your scaled plot example.

```
ListLinePlot[scaledData, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {44.015, 44.017}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am guessing that what you really wanted to do was to rescale `y` by subtracting `ymin` and using a much smaller divisor.

```
scaledData = Table[{(point[[1]] - xmin)/0.001, (point[[2]] - ymin)/0.00001}, 
                 {point, data[[210 ;; -1]]}]
```

If that is tried a plot that is closer to your example is the result

```
ListLinePlot[scaledData, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Create an interpolation function

One could make an interpolation function of the entire range of the scaled data or limit it to a range of interest.

```
f = Interpolation[scaledData[[1 ;; 10]]]
```

Now `f` can be used like any other pure function.

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi @ Jack LaVigne, thanks for your idea `Table[{...},{...}]`, which is very useful!. I think with high confidence that the first plot is a similar figures, which should be what I need. But how can I rescale it to do a best overlap, especially the initial part roughly $[0, 4]$, with the target figure, as show in my post. Kindly access the target data from my updated post. Thanks!